$Im[\log(\frac{3}{2})Li_{2}(\frac{3}{2})-Li_{3}(\frac{3}{2})+2Li_{3}(3)]=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log^{2}(2)-\frac{3\pi}{2}\log^{2}(3)+\pi\log(2)\log(3)$
When working on another problem, I got the following expression
\begin{align}
& \Im\left[\log\left(\frac32\right) \operatorname{Li}
_{2} \left(\frac32\right) - \operatorname{Li}
_{3}\left(\frac32\right) + 2\operatorname{Li}
_{3}(3)\right]
\\[2mm] = & \
-\frac{\pi}{2} \log^{2}(2) -\frac{3\pi}{2}\log^{2}(3)
+ \pi\log(2)\log(3)
\end{align}
I am new to PolyLogarithms in general and just learning about its properties.
Question: What properties of PolyLogarithms should I be referring to, to derive this systematically?
Note: I am not asking anyone to solve this for me, just guidance/hints.

Since you are looking for the imaginary part of the equation, the most important hint is that the polylogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_{s}(z)$of order $s \in \mathbb{R}$ is real if $ z< 1$ and complex if $z>1$ for $z\in \mathbb{R}$.
And the values of the imaginary part can be obtained from the formula:
$$ \boxed{\Im \operatorname{Li}_{s}(z) = -\frac{\pi \ln^{s-1}(z)}{\Gamma(s)}, \quad z>1}$$
Lets prove the case $s=2$. By definition:
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z) = -\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx$$
Suppose that $z>1$
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z) = -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx - \int_{1}^{z}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx$$
However $\displaystyle \ln(1-x)= \ln|1-x| + i\pi$ for $x>1$ where we take the principal branch of $\displaystyle \mathbf{\ln}$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\operatorname{Li}_2(z) &=& -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx - \int_{1}^{z}\frac{\ln|1-x|}{x}dx - i\pi\int_{1}^{z}\frac{1}{x}dx \\
&=&-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx - \int_{1}^{z}\frac{\ln|1-x|}{x}dx - i\pi\ln(z) 
\end{eqnarray*}
Taking the imaginary part in both sides:
$$\boxed{ \Im \operatorname{Li}_{2}(z) = -\pi\ln(z), \quad z>1} $$
Examples:
$$ \Im \operatorname{Li}_{3}(3) = -\frac{\pi}{2}\ln^2(3)$$
$$ \Im \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = -\pi\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = -\pi\ln(3)+\pi\ln(2) $$
